# React - State variable not being assigned as expected

Tags: reactjs

In my app, I have a custom protected route that renders content dynamically based on `isAuthenticated` variable shown below.

```
return  (
    <Route {...rest} render={() => {
        return isAuthenticated === true ? children : <Redirect to='/login' />
    }} />
)
```

The following code is above this:

```
const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(null)

useEffect(() => {
    const isAuth = async () => {
        try {
            const result = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/api/auth/isauth`, {headers: {'x-auth-token': localStorage.getItem("userJWT")}})
            setIsAuthenticated(true)
        }
        catch (err) {
            if (err) setIsAuthenticated(false)
        }
    }

    isAuth()
}, [])
```

When the user goes to this protected route, the `useState` is set to null by default, however this causes a `redirect even if the user is authenticated`. How do I set the state initally to the result of the `isAuth` function (true or false) in the `useEffect` instead of a value of `null`? Thanks.

Comment: Use a third "pending" state. In this case I think `null` is acceptable, you just need to conditionally ***not*** render the resultant route-children or redirect component until state is resolved/updated to `true`|`false`. A future issue I foresee is how your protected route doesn't handle changes in auth status other then when it mounts.

Comment: @DrewReese Any suggestions for reimplementation's?

Comment: `isAuthenticated === null ? ( <div>Authenticating...</div>  ) : isAuthenticated ? ( children ) : ( <Redirect to="/login" /> )`

Comment: @AjeetShah Thanks